# story about mind wipes, Nova starfighters, and humanities last pocket of existence?

Tags: story-identification, ebooks

I read an Ebook once, and I can remember most everything except for the title, which is annoying because I'd like to read it again. Here's most everything I can remember, may not be in chronological order.

- humans have been chased by some alien to one last little pocket in the galaxy
- I think the main navy consists of 1 huge ship, 2 smaller ships that can dock in it and a bunch of Nova starfighters. I'm not sure if there was another huge ship, I can't remember.
- the main character is poor and owes someone a lot of money
- lives with his gf or something
- skip ahead a bit, he meets the guy he owes money to in a space station garden
- guys offers him job in exchange for removing the debt
- I think he gets locked out of his ship by his gf around here
- main character takes job, and drinks some something laced with a plague
- later we see that the plague was created by main chracter's gf's dad, who was being paid a lot by the guy main character owed money to and his wife was hostage
- takes the place of a Nova pilot that was killed recently
- he goes to the huge ship in said main navy to try and find a way to slowly doom the ship
- ends up killing almost the entire crew, except for Nova pilots and a few others
- somewhere along the way realizes the captain is his son
- has to fight a ton of other star fighters of the guy he owed money to
- realizes his ex-gf was mind wiped and thinks her name is Star(name might be off)
- father-son reunion and then I think the story ends about there

Other than that, I remember I read the Ebook on a nook device from B&N, there were some typos in the book, and that's about it. Any idea what this book is called and where I can read it?

Comment: When did you read this?

Comment: @DavidW, a few years ago, probably 10-6 years ago

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book you are looking for is the first book in a series called dark space by Jasper t Scott
[Dark Space](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23365213-dark-space)

Just finished reading it about a month ago, too good a match for it to be anything else

- it has humanity hiding in a hidden part of space after stealthed aliens wipe out most of humanity,
- single large carrier left of imperial fleet with 2 cruiser sized ships docked in it plus fighter contingent
- Main character Ethan Ortane is a poor smuggler in debt to a gangster
- Lives on the ship with girl who wants to be his girlfriend but he still loves his wife who was lost in the alien invasion
- Gangster infects him with plague created by girl's dad and sends him to wipe out crew of carrier
- re-unites with his presumed dead son who was on the carrier in disguise
- Girl gets a brain implant that wipes her memory and turns her into a prostitute

There are 6 books in the series in total, Amazon had the series on sale for a few dollars which is why I bought it, not the best writing but had some nice ideas hidden within a fairly terrible execution.